# Disable modern experience for a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

Is there a way to disable the modern experience for the site collection and not all of SharePoint? I googled and saw where to disable the Modern and switch back to Classic at the admin level, but I don't want this for all of SharePoint. I don't want to completely miss out on all of the new things coming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to do at the site collection level or at the web level, it is only settable by CSOM/PowerShell. This is how we manage it in our PowerShell module for working with SharePoint Online.

```
function Set-NewExperience{
    <#
    .Synopsis
       Sets the document library experience for a site or web
    .DESCRIPTION
       Sets the document library experience for a site or web
    .EXAMPLE
       The following would disable the new experience for an entire site collection
       Set-NewExperience -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric" -Scope Site -State Disabled
    .EXAMPLE
       The following would disable the new experience for a single web
       Set-NewExperience -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric" -Scope Web -State Disabled
    .EXAMPLE
       The following would enable the new experience for an entire site collection
       Set-NewExperience -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric" -Scope Site -State Enabled
    .Link
    https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-for-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9
    #>
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]$Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet("Site", "Web")]
        [string]$Scope,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet("Enabled", "Disabled")]
        [string]$State

    )

    Begin{
        $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
        $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)
    }
    Process{

        if($Scope -eq "Site"){
            # To apply the script to the site collection level, uncomment the next two lines.
            $site = $context.Site
            $featureguid = new-object System.Guid "E3540C7D-6BEA-403C-A224-1A12EAFEE4C4"
        }
        else{
            # To apply the script to the website level, uncomment the next two lines, and comment the preceding two lines.
            $site = $context.Web
            $featureguid = new-object System.Guid "52E14B6F-B1BB-4969-B89B-C4FAA56745EF" 
        }
        if($State -eq "Disabled")
        {
            # To disable the option to use the new UI, uncomment the next line.
            $site.Features.Add($featureguid, $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None)
            $message = "New library experience has been disabled on $URL"
        }
        else{
            # To re-enable the option to use the new UI after having first disabled it, uncomment the next line.
            # and comment the preceding line.
            $site.Features.Remove($featureguid, $true)
            $message = "New library experience has been enabled on $URL"
        }
        try{
            $context.ExecuteQuery()
            write-host -ForegroundColor Green $message
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
    End{
        $context.Dispose()    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, do you know if this is still working? Created a new site collection, changed the links and un-commented for the site collection, ran the script, everything went smoothly, opened the site collection and everything the same as before.

Comment: @Yugo Sorry, I'm not sure. The pace of change in SPO is staggering, in 9 months this could very well be invalid. I don't have a means to test this any longer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, it's definitely not working for me but wanted to double check and see if I may be doing something wrong :). It's unbelievable that Microsoft to this day doesn't allow for a single site collection to use the modern experience in order to test out the changes without breaking everything in my production sites. I really enjoy the changes in the libraries but it breaks the whole look and feel as you switch from page to documents.

Comment: Confirming what @Yugo said. As of August 2017, I am disabling this feature on a single site collection, and the Modern look continues appearing.

Comment: A lot has changed in nearly a year, this may no longer be functioning as desired or MS might have broken something or altered how it works.

Comment: Thenka @EricAlexander but this doesn't work now as the feature itself is not present in the settings

Answer (score 0):

You can now set this for individual lists and libraries by going to list/library settings > Advanced Settings > List Experience.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9