# SharePoint modern experiences

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, classic

Hope you're well;

I would like to know what is powershell script to turn off modern experice for list and libraries in SharePoint Online.

kind regards,
Anees

Comment: check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200212/disable-modern-experience-for-a-site-collection

Comment: In your Office 365 Tenant Admin site check the Message Center for "SharePoint tenant opt-out for modern lists is retiring in 2019" to see the trend. I get the sense that Microsoft is pushing harder and harder on getting rid of the "Classic UI" experience in Office 365.