# Powershell Script - Switch All lists and libraries back to Classic

Tags: powershell, online, modern, classic

I hadn't opted out, I don't know how I missed the message about opting out but today all of our lists/libraries have switched over to modern.

I can no longer switch it back to classic in the admin center, and having to do it at the individual list/library level is going to be killer.

Is there any way that I can set all lists/libraries back to the classic experience using powershell?

I've been searching and looking but have found nothing.  I found this article on here, but from the comments it looks like this does not work?

[Disable modern experience for a site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200212/disable-modern-experience-for-a-site-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer below code :

```
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"


    $webUrl = 'Enteryoursiteurl'
    $username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter User Name" 
    $password = Read-Host -Prompt "Password for $username" -AsSecureString

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
    $clientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)

    $web = $clientContext.web
    $lists = $web.Lists
    $clientContext.load($lists)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    foreach($list in $lists){

        # Set the list experience (0 = Auto, 1 = modern, 2 = classic)
        $list.ListExperienceOptions = 2
        $list.Update()
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    }
```

Comment: Thank you Rohit, I found almost this same one on TechNet.  Appreciate the time and help. Cheers. :)